# Convert coordinate systems using SQLGeometery

Tags: sql-server, geospatial, sqlgeometry

One of my shape files looks like this:

```
POLYGON (
  -91.513078999999991 36.970298, 
  -87.01993499999999 36.970298, 
  -87.01993499999999 42.508337999999995, 
  -91.513078999999991 42.508337999999995, 
  -91.513078999999991 36.970298)
```

Another file is using SRID 3857:

```
POLYGON (
  -10033572.109485552 4727287.954831399, 
  -10033571.708142675 4727287.954831399, 
  -10033571.708142675 4727288.1439229213, 
  -10033572.109485552 4727288.1439229213, 
  -10033572.109485552 4727287.954831399)
```

Assuming I can figure out which coordinate systems are being used, how do I convert from one format to the other?

Comment: is it geography or geometry projections ? geometry, right ? my geography conversion failed on SRID 3857: "Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees."

Comment: I am using the Geometery type for both lists. According to STSrid, I am using 3857.

Comment: Please see my answer on your second question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275159/how-do-i-convert-srid-3857-to-decimal-degrees/24296642#24296642

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the GeometryToGeometry function from Pro Spatial, chapter 8.

Source code and data tables: http://www.apress.com/9781430234913