# How do I convert SRID 3857 to decimal degrees?

Tags: c#, sql-server, geospatial

How do I convert SRID 3857 formatted geometery coordinates into to decimal degrees?

My current stack is SQL Server 2014 and C#.

Comment: Do you just need to convert it to WGS84?

Comment: I need it to be in a format that http://leafletjs.com/ understands.

Comment: So what projection and format it understands?

Comment: Decimal degrees. I'm not seeing anything in the documentation more specific than that.

Comment: Well, seems like it's what I mentioned in the first comment. Just convert it to WGS84 and see if it points to a correct location

Comment: How do I do that given my data is currently in a SqlGeometry column?

Comment: Tried searching "sql server convert to wgs84" in google?

Comment: Yes. Mostly I run into comments such as "Coordinate transformation on ellipsoidal-based planar coordinates is beyond the scope of the SQL Server Spatial Tools project (the projection functions in this project are all based on a spherical Earth definition which is not suitable for this class of problem).  The specific case of WGS84 UTM coordinates falls into this category."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert coordinate systems using SQLGeometery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274136/convert-coordinate-systems-using-sqlgeometery)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274136/convert-coordinate-systems-using-sqlgeometery/24298296#24298296

SRID 4236 seems to work well enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Convert coordinate systems using SQLGeometery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274136/convert-coordinate-systems-using-sqlgeometery/24298296#24298296)

SRID 4326 seems to work well enough.

http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert them directly in SQL Server.  Quite simply it wasn't built to reinvent the Reprojection of spatial data in one datum to another.  When using SqlGeography, you can of course swap between SRIDs when both sets of coordinates use the same coordinate-type (decimal-degrees or grid-based), however when using SqlGeometry, they are simply planar coordinates based on the scale set by the bounds of the data you have and setting the SRID merely "groups" like-SRID spatial objects.

You'll need a Third-Party library or tool to do this for you.  Geographika notes some options at the following SO Link:

[Know of any C# spatial data libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184469/know-of-any-c-sharp-spatial-data-libraries)